# Obtaining representation of a real Lie algebra from the complexification "by restriction"

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I want to find the irreducible representations of the Lie algebra $\mathrm{so}(3,1)$.
I know the standard procedure goes on like

1. Complexify the Lie algebra, obtaining the complex Lie algebra $A_1\oplus A_1$;
2. Obtain all the irreducible representations of $A_1$
3. Build a representation of $A_1\oplus A_1$ from the product of two irreducible representations of $A_1$.

Now I should go back to the real algebra $\mathrm{so}(3,1)$, but I don't know how.
I know that if we have a (complex-linear) representation of a complex Lie algebra $L$ we can use its Weyl canonical basis (constructed using the Cartan subalgebra and the root system) to create a real-linear representation of the *compact* real section of $L$.
In my case, however, the compact real section is $\mathrm{so}(4)$ (or $\mathrm{su}(2)\oplus\mathrm{su}(2)$ if you like), not $\mathrm{so}(3,1)$.

In its article on the representation theory of the Lorentz group, [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group) says that

> [...] all irreducible representations of $\mathrm{so}(3,1)_{\mathbb{C} }$, and, by restriction, those of $\mathrm{so}(3,1)$ are obtained.

What "restriction" is it about?
Would someone explain how can we construct a representation of a real Lie algebra from the representations of its complexification?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3255785/96384.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra, then $\mathfrak{g}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}$ is a complex Lie algebra where we extend the Lie bracket by complex linearity. The map $i : \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}$ given by $X \mapsto X\otimes 1$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism.

Recall that a representation of a Lie algebra is just a Lie algebra homomorphism to $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$. Therefore, if $\rho : \mathfrak{g}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C} \to \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ is a representation of $\mathfrak{g}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}$, then $\rho\circ i : \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ is a representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ (because the composition of Lie algebra homomorphisms is a Lie algebra homomorphism).

Comment: So can we say that given a Lie algebra $g_0$ with basis $\{e_k\}$, its complexification $g$ and a representation $\rho$ of $g$, we can obtain a representation of $g_0$ by restricting to real-linear combinations of the elements $\rho(e_k)$, that is $\rho(i(e_k))$?

Comment: Moreover, can _every_ representation of the real algebra be found this way?

Comment: In general, I don't think every representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ arises this way.

Comment: If we are talking about representations on complex vector spaces, complexification *does* induce a bijection between complex rep's of a real Lie algebra and complex rep's of its complexification, cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1408894/96384 (and that's straightforward: every rep of the real $g$ is the restriction to $g$ of the complexified rep. of $g_{\mathbb C}$).

Comment: If, on the other hand, we start with rep's of $g$ on a *real* vector space $V$ (which is rarely studied actually), then one can first extend that to one on the complex vector space $\mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb R}V$, and then that to a rep of $g_{\mathbb C}$. Here however the induced map on isoclasses of irreducibles is definitely not surjective, i.e. not every complex representation comes from a real representation, cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1026919/96384; and I think (as Qiaochu seems to suggest in his comment there) it is not injective either.